# How to evaluate a Keras multi-class model with Micro F-Measure?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, evaluation, tf.keras

I want to evaluate my multi-class model in Tensorflow2/Keras with a Micro F-measures.

How can this be achieved?

Given a model

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('NNMODEL.h5')
```

and

Test datasets

```
testX 
testY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `scikit-learn`.

On the official documentation, you can see the following example(modified a bit):

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
y_true = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
y_pred = [0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1]
result = f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average = None) (an array of f1-scores for each class)
result_micro = f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='micro') (a float value)
```

You need to pay attention to set your '`average`' parameter to `None`; in this way, you receive the F1-score for each class separately. If you do want an overall F1-Score without F1-Score per class, use `average = 'micro'`.

Therefore, predict on each of the elements in `testX`, append the class-prediction to a list(this constructs the `y_pred` from the example above) and then `y_true` is actually the ground truth, i.e. `testY` in your case.